# WPF | Prism | Advance style don't apply to TabControl set as Region

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, prism, tabcontrol

**Description:** Advance styles (like MahApps.Metro) don't apply to TabControl if it is set as region in shell. Basic styling is applied. I tried putting Two TabControls in shell window, One marked as Region and the other as plain. Style did apply to non-region TabControl.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Create simple Prism application with 2 TabControl in Shell. Mark one TabControl as Region (Set RegionManager.RegionName) and other as simple
2. Add MahApps.Metro nuget package
3. Add MahApp resource dictionaries in Shell window resources

I'm not sure if I'm doing anything wrong or it's an issue with PRISM. I checked visual tree. Style is applied, but is not reflected in UI.

Any one facing similar issue or can help me resolve this issue?

Thanks in Advance!